# If the solar system is nearly flat, then why don't all the planets appear to lie on the same axis when viewed from earth?

Tags: orbit, solar-system, earth

For instance, consider the image below. The location of the planets seem to be so random relative to Earth. If the solar system was indeed flat, then I would expect the planets to lie on the same 'plane', and relative to us, it would look something like the second image. I mean, maybe Jupiter and Mars and Saturn could be on the same plane, but I fail to see how Venus would be.

What is wrong with my understanding here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a difference between perfectly and nearly. Zoom out to see the whole sky and show the orbits (press 'o' in stellarium)

Comment: The flat plane looks likea curve when projected onto the sky.

Comment: The diagram at the top of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_coordinate_system shows the ecliptic plane (the plane of the Earth's orbit) on the celestial sphere, but I admit that it's not a great diagram. A planetarium program like Stellarium is probably more useful.

Answer (score 13):

The first image is from a July [article](https://www.wdbj7.com/2020/07/18/five-planets-visible-in-the-early-morning-sky-this-weekend/) by TV meteorologist Brent Watts.
Approximating that view in [Stellarium](https://stellarium.org/):

[image: Jul 19 AM sky, center alt 20 deg]

The yellow arc is the [ecliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic), the plane of the Earth's orbit around the Sun.
It looks curved due to the [map projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection_in_cartography).
If the view is centered on it, the ecliptic looks straight:

[image: Jul 19 AM sky, centered on ecliptic]

Unlike the Sun, which appears on the ecliptic at all times, the planets can appear a few degrees north or south of it because their [orbital inclinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_inclination) are all slightly different.
The more another planet's orbit is inclined relative to ours, and the closer it approaches us, the more its ecliptic latitude varies.

Answer (score 1):

A plane looks like a curve when viewed on large angular scales on the sky (how could it be otherwise, think about a plane that cuts the north and south poles).

That plus the planets aren't in exactly the same plane.